# Is there any way to recover my email address?

Tags: support, login, email-addresses

If someone forgets their email address and password how can they again login to the site? I know how to do it when I forget password but I did not find any solution to recovering my email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are still logged on to Stack Exchange, you can go to your "Edit Profile & Settings" tab (go to your profile and there should be three tabs in the top left corner) and then to "My Logins". You should be able to find all the different ways you logged in to Stack Exchange, including your lost one.

[image]